# Trying to upload file to web browser using Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to automate the take of uploading a CSV file to a web browser.  If you click the button, a windows dialog box opens, you select the file, and it is uploaded as expected.  I'm trying to automate this small task.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<input name="csvFile" id="csvFile" class="ignore-inline-attach" type="file">
```

The code that I'm trying to get working looks like this:

```
import requests
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from webbot import Browser

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= r'C:/Users/ryans/OneDrive/Desktop/Briefcase/Python Scripts/chromedriver.exe')

web = Browser()
url = 'https://web_site'
web.go_to(url)

# 1st validation
web.type('email' , into='username')
web.click('Continue')

# 2nd validation
web.type('email' , into='username')
web.click('Next')

# password
web.type('pass' , into='password')
web.click('Next')

# Now you are logged in!!
url = 'https://web_page'
web.go_to(url)

#################################

# upload CSV Source File:
WebElement = webdriver.find_element_by_class_name('ignore-inline-attach')
WebElement.sendKeys("C:/my_path/test.csv");

#################################
```

When I run this code, I get the following error message:

```
AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'findElement'
```

I found a few sample scripts online, and tried several ideas, but I couldn't get anything working.  The two lines of code that I posted above seems like the best way to move forward, but I can't seem to get this working.  Does anyone here have any idea how to do this?  Thanks!

```
dir(webdriver)
# Result:
['ActionChains',
 'Android',
 'BlackBerry',
 'Chrome',
 'ChromeOptions',
 'DesiredCapabilities',
 'Edge',
 'Firefox',
 'FirefoxOptions',
 'FirefoxProfile',
 'Ie',
 'IeOptions',
 'Opera',
 'PhantomJS',
 'Proxy',
 'Remote',
 'Safari',
 'TouchActions',
 'WebKitGTK',
 'WebKitGTKOptions',
 '__builtins__',
 '__cached__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__path__',
 '__spec__',
 '__version__',
 'android',
 'blackberry',
 'chrome',
 'common',
 'edge',
 'firefox',
 'ie',
 'opera',
 'phantomjs',
 'remote',
 'safari',
 'support',
 'webkitgtk']
```

Comment: What are you getting using those instructions? an error? it doesn't do anything? Please elaborate a little bit more.

Comment: Are you submitting the form after that? What error are you getting?

Comment: Whoops.  I forgot to add that part.  I just updated my original post.

Comment: Can you try this line of code instead: `WebElement = webdriver.find_element_by_class_name('ignore-inline-attach')`

Comment: I added that line and now I get this: AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'find_element_by_class_name'

Comment: Can you please show line of code how you have created webdriver object ? Also the output of `dir(webdriver)`

Comment: I just updated my original post.

Comment: Instead of `webdriver.find_element_by_class_name`, you should use `driver.find_element_by_class_name`

Comment: Thanks!  I thought that was the key, but now I get this error: NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"ignore-inline-attach"}
  (Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.106)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
One very weird thing is that two Google Chrome browsers open.  I think there should be one...but there are two opening.  The first browser is blank and the second browser is populated, as I would expect it to be.

Comment: Oh, shoot, I think two different browsers are representing things differently.  In Chrome I am not seeing things that I am seeing in Firefox.  I think the code above will work, but I have to switch to Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is thrown because `find_element_by_class_name` function belongs to `webdriver.driver` instead of `webdriver`. Note that this code will open *two* browser windows, not one, because:

> "Web automation library for python which is based on the selenium framework"

If you look at the source you can see:

```
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driverpath , chrome_options=options)
```

It means that you open two tabs in these two lines:

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= r'C:/Users/ryans/OneDrive/Desktop/Briefcase/Python Scripts/chromedriver.exe')

web = Browser()
```

You don't actually need that. May be fixed in this way:

```py
import requests
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from webbot import Browser

web = Browser()
url = 'https://web_site'
web.go_to(url)

# 1st validation
web.type('email' , into='username')
web.click('Continue')

# 2nd validation
web.type('email' , into='username')
web.click('Next')

# password
web.type('pass' , into='password')
web.click('Next')

# Now you are logged in!!
url = 'https://web_page'
web.go_to(url)

# upload CSV Source File:
WebElement = web.driver.find_element_by_class_name('ignore-inline-attach')
web.driver.sendKeys("C:/my_path/test.csv");

# Close browser.
web.close_current_tag()
```

Glad to help you :)